# Slider issue when working with media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, media-queries

This is my first question on stackoverflow.. below is the code..

The problem is that when a browser is resized to smaller pixels everything works correctly except the slider box the slider box remains the same as in the normal pixels until it is refresh after refreshing the slider box is adjusted to correct size..

Other than that all the content is working correctly as the resizing done except of slider..

I hope I provided all the basic details of problem.. Look forward to have advice.. Thanks..

The original CSS

```
#cycle-slider img{
height:350px;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8f8;
background:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #f8f8f8 0px, #FFF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top, color-stop(0, #f8f8f8),color-stop(1, #FFF));
border:1px solid #ebebeb !important;
padding:4px;
}
```

At media query CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

#cycle-slider img{
height:270px;
width:90%;
margin-left:30px;
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Is the slider box something that you wrote yourself? Or are you using a third party plugin?

Comment: Also... Consider adding a jsfiddle to your post. The code that you have listed does not appear to be the problem. If I could see the full site or a jsfiddle, I could help you better identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. I m using third party plugin as you said i have took three screenshots.. Uploaded in skydrive here is the link http://sdrv.ms/1c1d8Zi

Comment: Moreover, this code part is the css for this slider.. There must be some thing from this part i think..